# c# What are these volume changing codes/messages

Tags: c#, audio, explorer

I found this script to change the System sound volume and it works. But what are these constant volume codes called and where can I find a full list of these codes that do more things.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

//Volume codes, or messages, or whatever they are called
const int VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
const int VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
const int VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;

SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x319, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)VOLUME_UP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are AppCommand messages.

0x319 is the Win32 Windows MSG for WM_APPCOMMAND, and the messages are more accurately APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP, etc...

AppCommand messages are messages sent to windows, which are handled at a global level and perform certain application functions.  These tend to be linked to Keyboard hotkeys and mouse button functions.

Your app gets first crack at processing any such messages, and if you do not handle them then your apps parent does.  If that doesn't handle them, then eventually it gets sent to a global message hook to process them.  The key point here is that other windows can trap these messages, so it's not a guarantee that sending these messages will accomplish the task.  Just like you might have seen where pressing the volume up or down on your keyboard might not always work when certain windows have focus.

You can find the details for all the messages in the Win32 API reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How come in the link you posted the, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP and APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN are diffrent from the values I posted.                                                                Also dose each program have it's own set of messages. Like would MicrosoftWord have its own messages.

Comment: @JackBarn - they aren't different values.  The problem is that the documentation is for the Win32 API, which is for the C language, and it does things at a lower level.  It has a macro called GET_APPCOMMAND_LPARAM() which retrieves the actual value from the param.  The value you listed above is a raw value for the entire param, including the device and keystate fields, but since you're not actually sending that data, it's all 0's.

Comment: @JackBarn - and no, these are global windows defined messages.  Certainly a program could define its own messages, but without some common definition, only that app would know about them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. IF you don,t mind. Is it possible to not enter the raw value, but instead something, cleaner, like instead of 0x80000, just 8(Witch did not work when I tried)

Comment: @JackBarn - You have to pass the raw value to the SendMessage function, so one way or another, you need that raw value.  0x8000 is not the same thing as 8.. not by a long shot.. use the Windows calculator in programmer mode and switch between Hex and Decimal and you will see.